# Downloaded APK files in android WebView not running

Tags: android, webview, apk

We have android app which is basically just webView.

We need to download APK files of this app (in case that the user needs an update).

Downloaded APK in chrome works. But if i download it in webView using following code, it is not running. You can click that file in filemanager how many times u want and nothing happens.

I already checked the files on windows and they seems to be both same. MimeType is correct. Any ideas how to fix the problem? Thanks

```
    public void enableDownload() {
    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
            if (hasStoragePermission() == false) {
                requestStoragePermission();
            } else {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType);

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Permissions in mainActivity:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

EDIT:
Download is behind log in so changing to Intent ( download over chrome ) is not possible.

Comment: Of course the downloaded APK is not running. Your code only downloads it. Search Stackoverflow of how to install an APK file.

Comment: Guess i need to clarify this. I know that my code doesn't contain installation part. I am trying to install it in File manager and there is nothing happening when i click it.